# CPP function can't get right output

Tags: c++, c++11

```
string readString(string p)
{
    string s;

    cout << p;
    cin >> s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    string oper = readString("? ");
    while (oper != "Q")
    {
        if (oper == "l")
            cout << "load complete" << endl;
        else if (oper == "+")
            cout << "add complete" << endl;
        string oper = readString("? ");
    }
}
```

When I input `l`, the output is `load complete`. But then I input `+`, it still outputs `load complete`. Why does it not output `add complete`?

http://ideone.com/JCDdXk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring *two* variables called `oper`.

```
int main()
{
    string oper = readString("? "); //HERE
    while (oper != "Q")
    {   
        string oper = readString("? "); //HERE
    }
}
```

The second line marked `HERE` declares a new variable in the current scope rather than updating the existing one in the containing scope. Change it to:

```
oper = readString("? ");
```

Comment: it works, but i still confused how does a new variable affect all these?

Comment: Because your new variable has automatic storage, so is alive until the end of its containing scope, i.e. the `while` loop. So all you are doing is constructing a new `string`, then destructing it near-instantly.